# how can I solve RAID 5 corrupted data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, corruption, raid

I installed Windows Server 2012 on my server using RAID 5. But a problem occurred on my server. I extracted the data from 10 hard disks with data recovery. When I attached the extracted data files in SQL Server 2012 the file is corrupted.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Isn't a backup restore an option in your scenario? What kind of problem occurred on your server, was it disk failure or something with Windows? What tool did you use for data recovery?

Answer (score 1):

> so how can i fix it

The answer will almost certainly be "restore from your last good backups", unfortunately.

> when attached...

As you say you have files to attach the problem may not be corruption due to problems with RAID, it is more likely corruption due to unsafe shutdown. without more information we really can't help in any more detail than this without a lot more detail from you though:

- Do the database files successfully attach? If so, what corruption are you seeing afterwards?
- Also, after attaching the files did you try running `DBCC CHECKDB` to see what it thinks about the state of the database?
- If the database files did not attach, how are you trying to attach the files and what response do you get (nothing, specific error messages, ...)

> ... solve RAID 5 corrupted data ...

If the problem *is* due to not reading the files correctly from the old RAID array then here is probably not the right place to ask, perhaps try serverfault instead.